# Как обновить данные в форме?

Tags: jquery, php

Сделал сохранение данных в личном кабинете - данные сохраняются, но хотелось бы, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку и перезагрузки страницы вернулись актуальные данные, а не старые, на данный момент показывает старые, и только потом после рефреша страниц - уже новые.

Пример кода:

```
<?if ($arResult['DATA_SAVED'] == 'Y' || $arResult["strProfileError"]):?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $(".sign_form").submit();
        });
    </script>
<?endif?>

<form class="sign_form" method="post" name="form1" action="<?=$arResult["FORM_TARGET"]?>?" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: window.location.href = "url" в помощь

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что вы вызываете сабмит формы по загрузке если в скрипте у вас данные сохранены или найдены ошибки формы? Как построен механизм отправки и обновление формы?